# Start rails development environment on android

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mobile

Is it possible to run the ruby on rails, development environment on android, like we do on mac/ubuntu/windows. If not then, please post comments to why isn't possible?

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: which version(s) of Android are you targetting? Also why would you want to use android?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, am targeting android 3.x for tablets.  And the reason for it is like, the future is in tablets and devices like it rather laptops or desktops.

Comment: The future may be in tablets for the common consumer, however, I don't see the laptop or desktop being replaced by tablets.  I can see them maybe becoming a specialty tool, but not being replaced.  The biggest reason I see for this is that it is pretty much impossible to program on a tablet without some server help.  Most IDEs I see for Android send their code off to a server which compiles it and sends it back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scripting Layer for Android (SL4A): http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/

For Ruby specifically: http://code.google.com/p/android-ruby/

Comment: thanks for the reply @Xjaphx, will check both the links, but at the moment am looking for a way to install gem on jruby support for android.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to consider [Rhodes](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/tutorial).  Rhodes is a Ruby MVC environment for building mobile apps for both Android and iOS.  It's folder structure is not exactly like rails, but similar enough that it should be an easy transition.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of running Rails on Android devices is very appealing to me. However, **I'm afraid it may not be easy or even possible at the moment.**

Key requirement for developing Rails applications is having a [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/) interpreter on device. As for as I know, the only real candidates for this are:

- Having [Scripting Layer for Android](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) (SL4A) along with [JRuby for Android](https://github.com/ruboto/sl4a_jruby_interpreter), or alternatively
- Using [Ruboto](http://ruboto.org/)

After somehow getting the Ruby running, you still would need to figure out how to install and use RubyGems, Rails itself as well as all other libraries your web application may depend on (they may or may not work on Android).

As a summary, at this moment I would be rather looking into some alternatives. For instance, installing RoR on some remove machine and connecting to it from Android device with some SSH application.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed reply @jsalonen.  I actually have got [Ruboto](http://ruboto.org/) and few other editors installed on my device.  Few of the editors while running are asking for (SL4A). And I couldn't figure out how to install that on my device.  If not rails at the moment, I want atleast few of the gems to get installed on my jruby or other editor support.  As probably i could run the ruby(.rb) files.